# CXF doesn't generate WSDL

Tags: spring, soap, cxf

I want to generate SOAP web services for my application using CXF. I have configured it and integrated it with Spring and all of this went fine.

I've compiled it successfully and I did not get any errors.

When I enter my services link: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/services` I get a list of the services that I had deployed, but when I want to enter the WSDL of any service, for example:  `http://localhost:8080/myApp/services/getUsers?wsdl` all I get is a 404.

Do you have any idea about my problem ?

Comment: What web-server did you deployed?

Comment: What server? tomcat? glassfish?!

Comment: Oh ! I'm sorry I wanted to write tomcat .